# How to - Graph Coloring in Prolog

Tags: algorithm, prolog, graph-theory, graph-coloring

I'm trying to make the simple graph coloring algorithm in Prolog, but I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the language. I know what I want to do - I want to go to a vertex, find all the other vertices connected to it, check my vertex's color, and depending on that, color the other vertices with different colors. I'm just having a hard time translating this to Prolog. If it was a C dialect or Java, it would be a piece of cake for me, but this is giving me fits.

This is what I have so far:

```
main:- graph_coloring.

%color_list([blue, red, green, yellow, white], colors).
%vertex_list([a, b, c, d], vertices).
%edge_list([(a,b),(b,c),(c,d)], edges).

%Our graph
color(blue).
color(red).
color(green).
color(black).
color(white).

%graph([a-b, b-c, b-d, c-d]).

vertex(a).
vertex(b).
vertex(c).
vertex(d).

%Subject to changing, so are asserted into listener at runtime.
init_dynamic_facts:-
    assertz(vertex_color(a, none)),
    assertz(vertex_color(b, none)),
    assertz(vertex_color(c, none)),
    assertz(vertex_color(d, none)),
    assertz(location(a)).

edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(b,d).
edge(c,d).

is_connect(A,B):-
    edge(A,B).
is_connect(A,B):-
    edge(B,A).

connections(Vertex):-
    edge(Vertex,X).
connections(Vertex):-
    edge(X,Vertex).

move(Vertex):-
    retract(location(_)),
    asserta(location(Vertex)).

paint_vertex(Vertex, Color):-
    retract(vertex_color(Vertex,_)),
    asserta(vertex_color(Vertex, Color)).

find_vertex_color(Vertex):-
    vertex_color(Vertex, X).


graph_coloring:-

    location(Current_vertex),
    vertex_color(Current_vertex, Curr_color),
    ( Curr_color =:= none ->
        connections(Current_vertex, Others),
        vertex_color(Others, Other_colors),
        paint_vertex(Current_vertex,
```

How can I complete this algorithm?

(edited: more code under graph_coloring)

Comment: Don't you want to go to an uncolored vertex, then choose a color that is not used by any neighbor vertex?

Comment: I'm starting with no vertices colored, although to be sure, it might be better to assign a color to the first one and do what you're saying.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what issue you are having?

Comment: I'm trying to do the graph coloring algorithm in prolog, but it is so different from anything else I've used, I'm not quite even sure where to start. For example, variables. They are used differently in prolog, and I've found they're even requested differently. For example, in C# I can say Variable_I_want = Method_that_returns_the_variable(). I can't quite do that in prolog, and I haven't gotten my head around how to do this the "prolog way".

Comment: Maybe you should start with something simpler, like assigning all your vertices a particular color.

Comment: What I would need then is a way to compare the vertices' colors in order to change them if I need to. For example, I can say in C#:

     color_list //contains all the colors
     vertex_list // all the vertices

     for v in vertex_list
     {
       // Find out colors of adjacent vertices to v, and if the color                                                          is the same, change it.

     }

This is essentially what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how.

Comment: When you are doing logic programming, you want to avoid thinking about things changing.  Instead, you are building an answer. To answer bigger questions, you ask smaller questions.  For example, to answer the question "how should all these vertices be colored?", you need to first ask the question "how should the first vertex be colored?", then "if the first vertex has color X, then what should the second vertex's color be?"

Answer (score 5):

I would like to mention this problem is a typical *constraint satisfaction problem* and can be efficiency solved using the CSP module of *SWI-Prolog*. Here is the full algorithm:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)). 

color(red).
color(blue).
color(green).

vertex(a).
vertex(b).
vertex(c).
vertex(d).
vertex(e).

edge(a,b).
edge(a,c).
edge(b,c).
edge(b,d).
edge(c,d).


colorGraph(ColorList) :- 
  findall((X, Y), edge(X, Y), Edges),
  findall(X, vertex(X), Vertexes),
  findall(hasColor(X, _), member(X, Vertexes), ColorList),
  createConstraint(Edges,ColorList),
  colorNodes(ColorList).

createConstraint([],_).
createConstraint([(V1,V2)|RL],ColorList):-
  member(hasColor(V1,C1),ColorList),
  member(hasColor(V2,C2),ColorList),
  dif(C1,C2),
  createConstraint(RL,ColorList).

colorNodes([]).
colorNodes([hasColor(_,C)|Nodes]) :-
  color(C),
  colorNodes(Nodes).
```

`color/1` indicates the colors available, `vertex/1` indicates the vertexes in the graph and `edge/2` defines the couples between the vertexes. Moreover, `colorGraph(?List)` determines the color of the vertexes, where `List` is a list of `hasColor(Vertex, Color)` clauses, `Vertex` being the colored vertex using `Color`.

Let's details each part of the algorithm above to understand what happens.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

It indicates to *SWI-Prolog* to load the module containing the predicates for *constraint satisfaction problems*.

```
colorGraph(ColorList) :- 
  findall((X, Y), edge(X, Y), Edges),
  findall(X, vertex(X), Vertexes),
  findall(hasColor(X, _), member(X, Vertexes), ColorList),
  createConstraint(Edges,ColorList),
  colorNodes(ColorList).
```

The predicate `colorGraph/1` is the entry point of the algorithm. It converts the clauses of edges/vertexes into lists, constraints the `ColorList` to have the list of vertexes defined and finally create the constraints on the colors and assign the colors (they are two separated operations).

```
createConstraint([],_).
createConstraint([(V1,V2)|RL],ColorList):-
  member(hasColor(V1,C1),ColorList),
  member(hasColor(V2,C2),ColorList),
  dif(C1,C2),
  createConstraint(RL,ColorList).
```

The predictate `createConstraint/2` simply states that two linked vertexes must have a different color. This is worth mentioning `dif/2` is a CSP predicate.

```
colorNodes([]).
colorNodes([hasColor(_,C)|Nodes]) :-
  color(C),
  colorNodes(Nodes).
```

The predicate `colorNodes/1` assigns the right color to the vertexes. Prolog is going to take care to assign the right colors based on the constraints defined above.

Finally, the results can be found by calling the predicate `colorGraph/1`, such as:

```
?- colorGraph(L).
L = [hasColor(a, red), hasColor(b, blue), hasColor(c, green), hasColor(d, red), hasColor(e, red)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, red), hasColor(b, blue), hasColor(c, green), hasColor(d, red), hasColor(e, blue)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, red), hasColor(b, blue), hasColor(c, green), hasColor(d, red), hasColor(e, green)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, red), hasColor(b, green), hasColor(c, blue), hasColor(d, red), hasColor(e, red)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, red), hasColor(b, green), hasColor(c, blue), hasColor(d, red), hasColor(e, blue)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, red), hasColor(b, green), hasColor(c, blue), hasColor(d, red), hasColor(e, green)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, blue), hasColor(b, red), hasColor(c, green), hasColor(d, blue), hasColor(e, red)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, blue), hasColor(b, red), hasColor(c, green), hasColor(d, blue), hasColor(e, blue)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, blue), hasColor(b, red), hasColor(c, green), hasColor(d, blue), hasColor(e, green)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, blue), hasColor(b, green), hasColor(c, red), hasColor(d, blue), hasColor(e, red)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, blue), hasColor(b, green), hasColor(c, red), hasColor(d, blue), hasColor(e, blue)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, blue), hasColor(b, green), hasColor(c, red), hasColor(d, blue), hasColor(e, green)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, green), hasColor(b, red), hasColor(c, blue), hasColor(d, green), hasColor(e, red)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, green), hasColor(b, red), hasColor(c, blue), hasColor(d, green), hasColor(e, blue)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, green), hasColor(b, red), hasColor(c, blue), hasColor(d, green), hasColor(e, green)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, green), hasColor(b, blue), hasColor(c, red), hasColor(d, green), hasColor(e, red)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, green), hasColor(b, blue), hasColor(c, red), hasColor(d, green), hasColor(e, blue)] ;
L = [hasColor(a, green), hasColor(b, blue), hasColor(c, red), hasColor(d, green), hasColor(e, green)] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to think in a way that is not natural for Prolog programs; that is, you are trying not to use recursion :) What I've came up with is the following, which however may not be entirely correct (it's late, and I don't have a good reputation when trying to think at times like this...:) )

Let's assume that you have the graph described by the following facts:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(b,d).
edge(c,d).
```

and that the available colors are

```
color(blue).
color(red).
color(green).
```

(you only need 3 colors to color a planar graph, so let's just use 3 here). Let's also assume that you want the answer to be given as a [Vertex-Color] list, where the list will contain a color for every vertex of your graph. I believe the following is a correct solution:

```
coloring([V-C]) :-
        color(C),
        \+ edge(V,_).
coloring([V-C,V1-C1|Coloring]) :-
        color(C),
        edge(V,V1),
        V \== V1,
        coloring([V1-C1|Coloring]),
        C1 \== C.
```

The first clause says that if there is no edge from V to any other vertex, just try all possible colors. The second clause says that vertex V will get color C, and vertex V1 will get color C1 if there is an edge from V to V1, where V != V1 and C != C1. (I also assumed that your graph is connected, i.e. there are no vertices which are not connected to other vertices).

And since we only want solutions where all the vertices have colors, we will only keep lists of length |V|, where V is the set of vertices you have. You can implement this restriction in various ways; I prefer to use "findall/3":

```
colors(X) :-
        coloring(X),
        findall(V,edge(V,_),List),
        length(List,Len),
        length(X,Len).
```

Now, by consulting this program and asking `|?- colors(X).` you will get all the possible color assignments for the vertices of your graph.

If anyone finds a problem I am almost sure there exists in the above solution, please, do let us know :)

Spyros

Comment: Thank you very much Spyros! Right now I'm trying to figure out why colors(X). is returning 'no', but now I'm understanding this a bit more. Should there be a list like [a-b, b-c, b-d, c-d], or should the code run with just the egde/2 and color/1 facts?

Comment: Apparently the list is the problem; after findall(...), length(List, Len) fails because for some reason the List is a "Bad Goal: H38".

Comment: I ran the above code in XSB-Prolog and it gives the correct (I hope :) )answer. Which Prolog compiler are you using? Maybe findall/3 requires different arguments in other Prologs...The use of findall/3 here is just to find how many vertices you have. You can replace it with the actual number, if you want. Just add a "vertices(4)" fact, which will contain the number of vertices you have in total, and replace the calls to findall and length(List,Len) with vertices(Len).

The only stuff I have in my source code are the definitions of edge/2, color/1, coloring/1 and colors/1.