# Prolog: check against duplicates in a list

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif

1. Write a predicate `allDistinct/1` whose parameter is a list (of symbols) and which succeeds if all symbols in the list are different.

   ```
   notin(A,[]).
   notin(A,[B|C]) :-
      A\=B,
      notin(A,C).

   allDistinct([]).
   allDistinct([_]).
   allDistinct([A|B]) :-
      notin(A,B), 
      allDistinct(B).
   ```

Comment: `allDistinct(B)` says that *any* list is all distinct! And... please indicate what you need help with. You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Besides unindented allDistinct(B) call I do not see why this code should not work. clause allDistinct([_]) seems to be redundant as well.

Answer (score 5):

Following up on the previous [sketch by @whd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35887553/4609915) we can proceed like this.

Based on [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/4609915) we can succinctly define `distinct/1` like so:

```
:- use_module(library(lists), [same_length/2]).

distinct(Es) :-
   iwhen(ground(Es), (sort(Es,Fs),same_length(Es,Fs))).
```

Sample queries using SICStus Prolog 4.5.0:

```
| ?- distinct([1,2,3]).
yes
| ?- distinct([1,2,3.0]).
yes
| ?- distinct([1,2,3.0,2]).
no
| ?- distinct([1,2,3.0,X]).
! error(instantiation_error,_283)
```

Answer (score 4):

Predicate `sort/2` sorts and remove duplicates from list. You can use it, compare length(`length/2` predicate) of new sorted list with old one if they differs there were some duplicated values.

Comment: Straight-forward, s(X). But **also ensure sufficient instantiation**!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those questions with a fair number of alternative, reasonable solutions. Assuming that common library predicates can be used, here is another one:

```
all_distinct(List) :-
    \+ (
        select(Element, List, Tail),
        select(Element, Tail, _)
    ).
```

A performance advantage of this solution is that it stops scanning the list as soon as it finds a duplicated element. But is it faster than solutions based on the standard `sort/2` predicate? Unclear as `sort/2` is an highly optimized predicate in most Prolog systems. Plus, let's no forget that, unless we're sure that all list elements are bound, we should be safe and check it (see @repeat answer).